# VertX Webserver static content webroot

Tags: javascript, java, gradle, webpack, vert.x

I've got two projects which I've created:

1. A web UI built using `webpack`
2. A `Vert.x` webserver written in `java` built using `Gradle`

I want to find a way to bring the resulting build dir contents of the first project into the second as the `webroot` which will be server up using the `StaticHandler`.

Is anyone aware of a clean way to do this? I want to preserve the two git projects as they are because I like using the `webpack dev server` for development of the UI and it generally feels cleaner to have them separated.

I was looking at potentially using the bitbucket pipelines build on my repo, however bringing the assets generated by the first project into the build of the second is where I'm facing issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a gradle task that before that depends on the jar task (so it runs before it) executes webpack compile into the resources directory. So when your jar task runs it bundles the compiled webpack code.